# margin() function in the R randomForest package not working

Tags: r, random-forest, margins

I am going through the package documentation for randomForest to see what different functions do. I got to the `margin()` function and the example in the documentation did not work for me.

The code I was trying was

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(1)
data(iris)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, keep.forest=FALSE)
plot(margin(iris.rf))
```

I get the error

> Error in unit(c(t, r, b, l), unit) :    (list) object cannot be
>   coerced to type 'double'

I have no idea what is going wrong.
I am on using Windows 10, R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31), randomForest v. 4.6-12

Comment: No error on my side.

Comment: what system are you on?

Comment: Okay, I restarted my session and for whatever reason it works now

Comment: Specify `randomForest::margin()` to avoid this error. There are `margin` functions in other packages (`ggplot2`).

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my session and everything worked again.

I must have had some sort of setting earlier in the documentation that screwed with how it interpreted the random forest.

Answer (score 0):

Just jumped into this issue myself. As stated in a comment, the solution lies in specifying the package under which the *margin* function is desired to be used from; in this case *randomForest*
Thus the code line to change is

```
plot(randomForest::margin(iris.rf))
```